# Changing the values of array by the distance of the indexes (c)

Tags: c, arrays, binary

I'm having hard time with this one:
I need to write a function in C that recieving a binary array and his size, and the function should calculate and replace the current values with the distance (by indexes) of each 1 to the closest 0.
for example: if the function recieve that array `{1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1}` then the new values of the array should be `{2,1,0,1,2,1,0,1}`. It is known that the input has atleast 1 zero.

So the first step I tought about was to locate pair of zeros (or just 1 if there is only 1) and set them as 2 indexes (`z1`, `z2`). Then I set another index `i` 
that check everytime which zero is the closest to him (absolute value) and then the diffrence between `i` and `z1` or `z2` would be the new value.

I have the plan but things are not going exactly as I planned. Basicly I deleted the code (it wasn't good anyway) so I would appreciate any help. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is based on two things

- Keep an array `left[i]` which has the distance of nearest `0` from index `i` from left to right.
- Keep an array `right[i]` which has the distance of nearest `0` from index `i` from right to left.

Both can be calculate in single loop iteration. `O(n)`.

- Then for each position get the minimum value of `left[i]` and `right[i]`. That will be the answer for `1` staying in position `i`.

Overall the time complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: By "keep an array.." you mean to create another array? Thats sound intresting.

Comment: @OfekPintok.: Keep 2 arrays...yes. But based on the precise constraints it can be modified also.